# TextEdit key bindings modified in DefaultKeyBinding.dict stopped working

Tags: keyboard, textedit

I have customized text editing bindings in ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict but they all stopped working in TextEdit.app when I upgraded to Lion. They still work fine in other Cocoa apps like Safari.

The system default bindings like <kbd>^F</kbd> for `moveForward:` work as usual.

Has anyone else who uses DefaultKeyBinding.dict noticed this? Is there a way to fix it or any other way of customizing the key bindings in TextEdit?

Comment: The custom keybindings work normally for me in TextEdit. Have you tried replacing your DefaultKeyBinding.dict with something like `{"a"=(insertText:,"test");}`?

Comment: @LauriRanta thanks; knowing that I was the only one with the problem got me to finally investigate it properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that I had moved the actual DefaultKeyBinding.dict file somewhere else for version-control purposes and symlinked to it.

Most apps were loading the file through the symlink, but TextEdit (and, it turns out, a couple other apps that I thought just didn't support key bindings) must do something different and didn't see it.

So, oops, lesson learned. Don't symlink your system configuration files.

Comment: Thank fcuk for your answer. I was completely reinstalling my user account because I thought Pages/Keynote had some hidden user setting that kept them locked onto an older version of my *DefaultKeyBinding.dict*. Like you I had version controlled it after that change. I still need to version control my user account settings, which are spread across directories and files throughout my `~`/home. It had seemed like symlinks to files in a *usersettings* project were the answer. Instead I will version control my entire home, *.gitignore* all files by default, and whitelist the files I want.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem myself with symlinking this file, but I didn't want to give in to this limitation, so I created a git `pre-commit` hook to update ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict whenever my version was committed.

Here is the code (for Git):

```
#!/bin/bash


if [[ $(git diff --cached --name-only | grep '.configurations/DefaultKeyBinding.dict' | wc -l) -eq 1 ]]; 

then
   FILE_PATH_IN_LIBRARY=~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
   BASE_DIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
   FILE_PATH_IN_SCM=${BASE_DIR}/.configurations/DefaultKeyBinding.dict

   NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)
   BRIGHT=$(tput bold)
   GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)

   printf "${BRIGHT}${GREEN}The file <%s> was modified, updating %s${NORMAL}\n" $FILE_PATH_IN_SCM $FILE_PATH_IN_LIBRARY

   cp $FILE_PATH_IN_SCM $FILE_PATH_IN_LIBRARY
fi
```

To use it all you need to do is replace `FILE_PATH_IN_SCM=${BASE_DIR}/.configurations/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` with the location of the file in your Git Repository.

If you never created a git hook before (this was my first) - you need to place this code in:

```
<your-git-repo>/.git/hooks/pre-commit
```

Don't forget to run `chmod +x <your-git-repo>/.git/hooks/pre-commit` to make it executable.

Afterwards every commit involving this file will show something like:

```
The file </Users/myuser/.scripts/.configurations/DefaultKeyBinding.dict> was modified, updating /Users/myuser/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
```